# how to use less variables in vue components?

Tags: vue.js, less, vue-composition-api

I have imported the .less file to the vue component, but it still gives me an error.

I define the variables in `base.less` under `assets/less`.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  src: url(../fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf);
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@button-bg-color: #809c2c;
@button-bg-color-hover: #99b056;
@button-border-radius: 7px;
@button-font: 'Poppins';
```

And import it to `App.vue`.

```
<style lang="less" scoped>
@import './assets/less/main.less';

header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 2em;

  .header-title-nav {
    width: 60%;
  
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;

    i {
      width: 6.25em;
      height: 6.25em;
    }

    .logo {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }

  .header-btn {
    background-color: @button-bg-color;
    border-radius: .5em;
    width: 12.5em;
    height: 7.8125em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: .8em;
    font-weight: 600;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    &:hover {
      background-color: #99b056;
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

The error message appears in the line under `.header-btn` in VScode is property value expected.

I installed less, and variables are able to use in main.less.

There's others who encounter the same problem just add an import statement and solved, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev I don't understand the `bundle`. the project has no `dist` folder, I don't have built it. It's a relative path to the imported file.

Answer (score 0):

You set variables in `base.less` and include `main.less`...
Also, if you are using `vite`, and want the `less` varables to be awailables in all components, set this in `vite.config.ts`:

```
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      less: {
        additionalData: '@import "@/assets/less/variables.less";',
      },
    },
  },
})
```